# What is an emulator? How to write a basic http packet emulator?

Tags: httpresponse, packet, packet-capture

So I basically captured a packet using Wireshark and I want to emulate it. Can someone give me some information about an emulator and some tips or even help and answer it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replay the captured traffic then here are some tools for that:

- [Tcpreplay](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/)
- [Colasoft Packet Player](http://www.colasoft.com/download/products/download_packet_player.php)
- [PlayCap](http://www.signal11.us/oss/playcap/)

Comment: Well, I don't really know what you mean with replay, but all I know that I have to emulate the http packet , I don't even understand what emulate means :/

Comment: If you do not know what you are supposed to achieve then nobody is able to help you. Perhaps you should first go back to the person who gave you that task and ask for clarification.

Comment: Well, I'll try to clear it as I can. An heartbeat server sends me an http request to check for the connection, If It finds something is not good it disconnects me. What I want to do is emulate this http request.

Comment: Well, I'll try to clear it as I can. An heartbeat server sends me an http request to check for the connection, If It finds something is not good it disconnects me. What I want to do is emulate this http request.

           Here is an example of http request I'm talking about : `http://14.63.196.240/x2/solomon.cgi?q=UiM4cPrikzhEYy6KWh6IAy6iccc_hbBBhzp1hbjJklNccjxcnci3cccc2NKqccccEgfEscpcccccccccccccckNocciN_2chINcccccccccccccciHcccv1ccciXcjxcexi0ctPcdHiCcrHcAHc-ccccDcrppWNzcccccjcc`



Heartbeat server script: `http://14.63.196.240/x2/solomon.cgi`

Comment: just use wget or curl command line tool? Or a browser? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Does emulate mean post http respond? Thank you very much if it means that, I know what you said but I didn't know the word emulate.

Comment: Well, I guess to "emulate" in this context means to repeat the request the same way it was originally made. Using the same request type, same headers, etc.

Comment: The problem is the `http://14.63.196.240/x2/solomon.cgi?q=UiM4cPrikzhEYy6KWh6IAy6iccc_hbBBhzp1hbjJk‌​lNccjxcnci3cccc2NKqccccEgfEscpcccccccccccccckNocciN_2chINcccccccccccccciHcccv1ccc‌​iXcjxcexi0ctPcdHiCcrHcAHc-ccccDcrppWNzcccccjcc`

keeps changing like it may change to : `/x2/solomon.cgi?q=wopwizWikzhEXLBKWj6IAy6icciPdzCTZ06Md5pcaxWk3ejpugznsrcccccccccciHccccjcccb84444cccWi3grFNfLVZprcccccccccccacccccxccctcSTHycci_aAUGnssccccccccccccccccXccccicccckkHJWNcc`

Is there any solve to this?

Comment: Obivously you need to understand how that payload is generated, in order to "emulate" it (if you need to change it also). I have a feeling you are quite clueless, so good luck with that. :-P

Comment: Yeah, I'm really newbie to packets and sockets .. I only study C++ and reverse engineering. Is there any tip on knowing that?

Comment: This has nothing to do with packets and sockets -- these are all much lower level. You're dealing with high-level protocol like HTTP (it really doesn't matter for your needs that underneath the HTTP connection there is a socket). But it seems that even HTTP-protocol level is too "low level" -- if you need to change that parameter, you need to understand the application that is generating those HTTP requests. I would look into the source code of the solomon.cgi or the source code of the client that is putting those requests together.

Comment: If this is a hacking/reverse-engineering exercise then good luck with that -- not my field of competence.

Comment: Yes, it is bypassing an anti cheat. I sucessfully bypassed it but the heartbeat check always disconnect me..

Comment: As I understand, you have full control over the client (a game)? If the game is written in Java, you could try decompiling it to understand how that payload is put together. If not, you'll have to read machine code :-P I would guess there is some sort of timestamp and user/session identifier in there, usually in encrypted form.

Comment: Yes, I mostly have this. It is written in C++. I can only read it in assembly, I will try to see that later. Thanks for helping